# Application.Input box to enter range for copy and paste options

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to copy and paste from one sheet to another, whereby the cells should be copied with the pastelink feature, while making use of the input box to let the user enter the range where he wants to paste the copied data. The code works within the same sheet but not on a different one. Even if it works, it does not recognise the range I have entered in the input box. Instead, it recognises the cursor and pastes whereby the cursor is in the destination worksheet.

This is the code I used for the copying and pasting from sheet 1 to sheet 2. Is there any problem with the codes for which why it does not recognise the range I have entered in the input box?

```
Sub tryuserinput()


Dim rng As Range
Dim inp As Range

Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 37
Set inp = Selection

Set rng = Application.InputBox("Copy to", Type:=8)
inp.Copy

rng.Select

Worksheets("Sheet2").Paste Link:=True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim rng As Range, inp As Range

    '~~> Check if what the user selected is a valid range
    If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then
        MsgBox "Select a range first."
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Set inp = Selection
        inp.Interior.ColorIndex = 37
    End If

    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Copy to", Type:=8)

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        rng.Parent.Activate
        rng.Select

        inp.Copy
        ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Revised because...I didn't research. Just use this line of code after you choose the range in other sheet.

```
inp.Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range(rng.Address)
```

Comment: It gives me an erorr message like"Paste method of worksheet class failed"

Comment: Try to update everything below your input box to this.

Comment: The code works however the cells do not reference to each other. Any ways to incorporate paste link? Thank you so much!